# nodeJS share variable between modules

Tags: node.js

i have a problem with my project, i need sharing the configurations parameters between modules, y have my entry point

app.js

```
const { requestConfiguracion }  = require('./clases/servicios');
( async () => {
    const dbConfig              = await requestConfiguracion();     
})();
```

servicios.js

```
const axios         = require('axios').default;

const requestConfiguracion = async () => {
    try {
        const request   = await axios.get('http://localhost/config/getConfig');
        return request.data;        
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
    }
}

module.exports = {
    requestConfiguracion,
}
```

I need that the configuration in dbConfig is available for the other modules.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separated module to read and export that dbConfig.

```js
// db-config.js
const { requestConfiguracion } = require('./clases/servicios');
let dbConfig = null;

module.exports.getDbConfig = async () => {
    if (dbConfig) return dbConfig; // cache dbConfig for next time
    dbConfig = await requestConfiguracion();
    return dbConfig;
};
```

And in other modules:

```js
// app.js
const { getDbConfig } = require('./db-config');

async function someFunction() {
    const dbConfig = await getDbConfig();
    // do something
}
```

Since your `requestConfiguracion()` function is an async function, you have to use `await` every time trying to get that config.